# Replace Into in SQL Server 2008

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, migration

I try to do a migration but i have problem with this query :

```
$DB->query("replace into periodetojour(idperiode,idjour,heure)
            values('".addslashes($idperiode)."','2','".addslashes($mardi)."')");
```

I saw that `REPLACE INTO` can't be used in SQL Server 2008 and that i hav to use `MERGE INTO`

My problem is that i don't find any of my query which is working by using `MERGE INTO` so i am probably not using it well. Do you have any idea how can i change it with MERGE INTO and is it an obligation to change it in SQL Server 2008 ?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Are you trying to migrate data from one table to another?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. Are you looking for a way to use `Merge`? I am not a sql-server user but found [this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, the [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb510625.aspx) statement would look like this:

```
$DB->query("MERGE INTO periodetojour dst 
            USING ( 
              SELECT '".addslashes($idperiode)."' idperiode, 
                     '2' idjour, 
                     '".addslashes($mardi)."' heure 
            ) src  
            ON src.idperiode = dst.idperiode  
            WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET  
              dst.idjour = src.idjour, 
              dst.heure = src.heure  
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (idperiode, idjour, heure)  
              VALUES(src.idperiode, src.idjour, src.heure)");
```

This is assuming that `idperiode` is your primary key. If the primary key is composed of `(idperiode, idjour)` you'll have to adapt the `ON` clause as well as the `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET` clause accordingly:

```
            -- [...]
            ON src.idperiode = dst.idperiode  
            AND src.idjour = dst.idjour
            WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET  
              dst.heure = src.heure
            -- [...]
```