# Replace equivalence for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace Into in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385933/replace-into-in-sql-server-2008)

How can I do this

```
REPLACE INTO "product_to_store" ("store_id", "product_id") VALUES ('1', '1')
```

in SQL Server 2008?

I need to replace this values no just update

Comment: The problem is that i want to replace the values for this filds (the values showed in the post are irrelevant) but server 2008 not allows replace instrucction.. right now im working with the reference posted from Raphael..

Comment: If you are now using a MERGE statement please add the actual code into the question. Or ask a new question regarding a MERGE statement issue.